# Realm Migration Fail with Error : Migration Required, or object has already been opened with a different schema version

Tags: ios, swift, realm

here is the code for the migration (in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions){

```
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 3,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            // The enumerateObjects:block: method iterates
            // over every 'Person' object stored in the Realm file
            migration.enumerate(User.className()) { oldObject, newObject in

                if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                    newObject!["crashTest"] = ""
                }
                if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {

                }
            }
    }) let realm = try!Realm()
```

Here is the error:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm Code=0 "Migration is required due to the following
>   errors: 
>   - Property 'crashTest' has been added to latest object model." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the
>   following errors: 
>   - Property 'crashTest' has been added to latest object model.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-700.1.101.15/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 50

Comment: Have you checked whether the schema version of your Realm file is actually lower than `3`, what you specified in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in local development only, I suggest you to reset your realm database instead do a migration. You can reset the database by deleting the app on your simulator or devices. Alternatively you can try to use NSFileManager to delete the realm file before accessing the database.
  `let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: defaultPath!)`